# Custom Trimmed Mean function returning 'NaN' in R

Tags: r, debugging, nan

I am trying to build a trimmed mean function, but the function is returning 'NaN' I am not sure where in the function the issue resides

```
trimmed_mean <- function(x, trim) {
    n = length(x)
    ## the number to trim on each end
    n_to_trim = floor(trim * length(x))
    ## sort the vector
    x_sorted = sort(x)
    ## the indices of the elements to trim at the low end
    lo_idx = 1:n_to_trim
    ## the indices of the elements to trim at the high end
    hi_idx = (n - n_to_trim):n
    ## get rid of the lowest elements
    x_trimmed = x_sorted[!lo_idx]
    ## get rid of the highest elements
    x_trimmed = x_trimmed[!hi_idx]
    return(mean(x_trimmed))
}

## should give 2.75
trimmed_mean(c(-20, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 20, 2, 3, 4), trim = .1)
```

It should return 2.75.

Comment: Stare at this a bit and perhaps you will see why it fails: `10*.1 == 10
[1] FALSE`. There are other bugs in the code. If you use `print` or `cat` as debugging tools you can perhaps find the rest of the errors, possibly also do to faulty understanding of floating point gotchas.

Comment: Nope the next error (which becomes apparent when following the debugging advice immediately above is related to  error when attempting logical indexing. Since you failed to provide any evidence of attempts at debugging, I'm not sure why the tag was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty simple thinko here.

You need to use `-` rather than `!` to exclude elements that are specified numerically:

```r
x_trimmed = x_sorted[-c(lo_idx, hi_idx)]
```

rather than the corresponding two lines with `!`

I found this by running `debug(trimmed_mean)` and then running the `trimmed_mean(...)` call again (I didn't see it immediately). When I found the step that had surprising results, I was able to look more closely at that line and see what was wrong. (You can also do this the old fashioned way by introducing lots of `cat()` and `print()` statements in your code to track the results, but `debug()` (or `debugonce()`) is more convenient. You can also set debugging flags interactively in RStudio.)

Also note that slightly weird things will happen if `n_to_trim` gets rounded down to 0 ...

Comment: One thinko and one floating point confusion.

Comment: are you referring to the possible surprise from `floor(trim * length(x))`? `floor(10*0.1)` happens to be 1 as expected, although I agree there's room for surprise there ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes. The original example had 10 items and so the index calculated would be 0. I assumed possibly incorrectly that this was the cause of the NaN, but I didn't see the error of using a negation operator rather than a negative numeric until I `print()`ed everything out step by step.